# ProgrammingError Django 1.7 (1146 error, marketing slider does not exist)

Tags: python, mysql, django, webfaction, mysql-error-1146

I have now managed to get an ecommerce page working fine on local host, however, when I am trying to get it working on webfaction I get the admin page working and the static files working for the .com/admin however for the main page I get this error in my browser.  Do you have any suggestions?

```
ProgrammingError at /

    (1146, "Table 'mycommerceapp_db.marketing_slider' doesn't exist"))
```

Comment: you gotta reformat this

Comment: How do i do that?  Sorry I am very new to this

Comment: Did you migrate your database at WebFaction, or at least import a local export of your DB to your database there? You're missing tables in your database - that's what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this by removing my mysql database and starting a new postgresql one on webfaction and updating my settings.py for postgres.
Hope this is of use.